# Google Sign In issue asking to update to latest

Tags: oauth, google-plus-signin, google-signin

All,

I am trying to access Google Sign in API today. But it said below message and stopped signing with the google account. This has been working till yesterday without any issues. Is there any announcement from Google about this?

" A new version of GoogleSignIn is available: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version 2.0.1 (as of 06.12.2015) has been released. If you run `pod update` in your project folder, it should get the latest library and update your project to use it.

Comment: @PaulRaj did you added as pod now?